# Invalid UUID string: 1

Tags: java, string, postgresql, casting, uuid

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 1 while casting string to uuid.

```
String uuid=uuidToBase64(Id);
String uuid1=uuidFromBase64(uuid);
String updateCompletionFlagQuery = "UPDATE tableA SET FLAG='1' WHERE ID=?  AND VEHICLE_ID=?      
getJdbcTemplate().update(updateFlagQuery,uuid1,vehicleId);
```

Comment: Post sample data.

Comment: Where does `Id` come from? It appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 3):

UUID's **must** follow the format outlined below:

xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 2):

it is because you have declared uuid1 as String in below line

```
String uuid1=uuidFromBase64(uuid);
```

The function is expecting it to be type of UUID for example look at the below example

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix , the invalid UUID error is gone now, but getting the below error: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE  tableA SET FLAG='1' WHERE ID=CAST(? as uuid)  AND ID1=?]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. : Tried casting the uuid UPDATE tableA SET FLAG='1' WHERE ID=CAST(? as uuid)  AND ID1=?], but didn't work

Comment: CREATE CAST (varchar AS uuid)
  WITH INOUT
  AS IMPLICIT;
  ALTER TYPE uuid OWNER TO myOwner : This Cast creation in Database fixed the bad grammar exception

Comment: there is no need to cast in the prepared statement, just use uuid.toString()